# Einstein Email Recommendations - Default Values

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I have the email recommendations set up and functioning but I have some contacts in the DE I'm using to send off of that do not seem to have any recommendations, I assume they have not had any site activity and therefore have no data to use as recommendations.

Is there a way to set a default value if a contact doesn't have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure in the [Scenarios](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_einstein_recommendation_scenarios.htm&type=5) for the recommendations logic that there are one or two Site Data Scenarios down towards the bottom of the scenarios being used, like "Top Sellers", "Most Viewed" etc. These scenarios do not require any profile or affinities and are simply based on wisdom of the crowds. These generic scenarios can function to serve your fallback/default recommendations for contacts with little information for Einstein to work with.

Comment: I already have them set up that way using both Top View and Top Sellers and I'm still getting the same issue